# restore mysql backup file using php

Tags: mysql, php

I can get backup file for mysql database using php and every thing gone nice , but when I trying to restore this backup file I have mysqli error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO radpostauth VALUES ('289','ah','ah','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 10:' at line 7
```

in other hand when I take the query which is writed into the file and past it in php my admin directly it executed without any error I am sure that the query is right 
I have 3 empty line between every insert query when I run the file the first insert query is executed but the error is show when want to execute the second insert query

> INSERT INTO radcheck VALUES  ('1229','ah','Cleartext-Password',':=','ah','','','','','','','','');
>
> INSERT INTO radpostauth VALUES  ('289','ah','ah','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 10:04:22'), ('290','muh','asdfghjkl','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 10:05:30'), ('291','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 11:21:48'), ('292','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 11:55:40'), ('293','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 11:59:03'), ('294','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 12:52:58'), ('295','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 13:41:41'), ('296','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-14 14:50:40'), ('297','sda','sad','Access-Accept','2017-08-15 09:45:40'), ('298','ah','ah','Access-Accept','2017-08-16 12:52:09'), ('299','ah','ah','Access-Accept','2017-08-17 09:19:53');

why I have this wrong

Comment: Try using [`mysqli::multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of `mysqli::query()`. It allows the execution of multiple queries at once.

Comment: thank you for your reply but  I had same error

Comment: I am so sorry it worked perfect thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`mysqli::multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of `mysqli::query()`. It allows the execution of multiple queries at once.